# Using POI To read/write a doc with the full POIFSFileSystem

Tags: java, apache-poi, doc

I have the following issue, as everybody it seems, I want to replace some items with others in Word doc.
Issue with the issue is, the doc contains headers and footers which are part of the `POIFSFileSystem` (I know this because reading the FS / writing the doc back -without any changes- loses these informations, whereas reading the FS / writing it back as a new file doesn't).

Currently I do this :

```
POIFSFileSystem pfs = new POIFSFileSystem(fis);
HWPFDocument document = new HWPFDocument(pfs);

Range r1 = document.getRange(); 

…
document.write();

ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(50000);
pfs.writeFilesystem(bos);
pfs.close();
```

However this fails, with this error:

```
Opened read-only or via an InputStream, a Writeable File is required
```

If I don't rewrite the document, it works fine, but my changes are lost.
The other way around if I only save the document, not the filesystem, I lose the header/footer.

Now the problem is, how can I update the document while "saving as" the entire filesystem, or is there a way to force the document to contain everything from the file system?

Answer (score 0):

The `HWPF` stuff is always in scratchpad because the `DOC` binary file format is the most horrible of all the `H`orrible formats. So it will really not be ready and also will be buggy in many cases.

But in your special case, your observations are not reproducible. Using `apache poi 4.0.1` the `HWPFDocument` contains the header story, which also contains the footer stories, after creating from `*.doc` file. So the following works for me:

Source:

[image]

Code:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.hwpf.*;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.*;


public class ReadAndWriteDOCWithHeaderFooter {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  HWPFDocument document = new HWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("TemplateDOCWithHeaderFooter.doc"));

  Range bodyRange = document.getRange();
  System.out.println(bodyRange);
  for (int p = 0; p < bodyRange.numParagraphs(); p++) {
   System.out.println(bodyRange.getParagraph(p).text());
   if (bodyRange.getParagraph(p).text().contains("<<NAME>>")) 
    bodyRange.getParagraph(p).replaceText("<<NAME>>", "Axel Richter");
   if (bodyRange.getParagraph(p).text().contains("<<DATE>>")) 
    bodyRange.getParagraph(p).replaceText("<<DATE>>", "12/21/1964");
   if (bodyRange.getParagraph(p).text().contains("<<AMOUNT>>")) 
    bodyRange.getParagraph(p).replaceText("<<AMOUNT>>", "1,234.56");
   System.out.println(bodyRange.getParagraph(p).text());
  }

System.out.println("==============================================================================");

  Range overallRange = document.getOverallRange();
  System.out.println(overallRange);
  for (int p = 0; p < overallRange.numParagraphs(); p++) {
   System.out.println(overallRange.getParagraph(p).text()); // contains all inclusive header and footer
  }

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("ResultDOCWithHeaderFooter.doc");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

 }
}
```

Result:

[image]

So please do checking it again and tell us exactly what is not working for you. Because we need reproducing that, please do providing a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as I have done with my code.

Comment: I'd love to give you the file causing the trouble but it can't be done. What I know is that the header is partially there, but there is a picture in it that is simply lost. (The template isn't create using POI but probably with word).

Either way, i'll use the DOCX as this one isn't plagued by this issue... (Wither word saving the file as... suppresses it or POI handles it correctly.)

Comment: @gougoul: "the header is partially there, but there is a picture in it that is simply lost": Also cannot reproducing. If my `TemplateDOCWithHeaderFooter.doc` contains a picture in the header, it will not be lost in my `ResultDOCWithHeaderFooter.doc` after running my code.; "Either way, i'll use the DOCX": Yes, this will probably be best if possible. In 21th century those horrible binary document formats such as `*.doc` should silently die.

Comment: Yes that's definitely true. Thanks for your help anyway !

Ten years ago I spent ages writing some code to generate XLS files. What a mess